# How to increase String.Index in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3, operators

In swift2.3
++ operator use for string.index increase

eg.
i++

I changed to swift 3 that code happen 
"
Unary operator '++' cannot be applied to an operand of type '@lvalue String.Index' (aka '@lvalue String.CharacterView.Index') " in swift 3

I rewrite 
eg.
i += 1

but this code can't solve.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`String.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/index) is a typealias for [`String.CharacterView.Index`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.characterview.index). The index cannot, on its own, be increased. Rather, you can use the [`index(after:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.characterview/1779530-index) instance method on the `CharacterView` that you used to extract the index.

E.g.:

```
let str = "foobar"
let chars = str.characters

if let bIndex = chars.index(of: "b") {
    let nextIndex = chars.index(after: bIndex)
    print(str[bIndex...nextIndex]) // ba
}
```

Or, given that you have an index (e.g. `str.startIndex`), you can use the `index(_:, offsetBy:)` instance method available also directly for `String` instances:

```
let str = "foobar"
let startIndex = str.startIndex
let nextIndex = str.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
print(str[startIndex...nextIndex]) // fo
```

Answer (score 9):

`String.Index` doesn't have a `++`, `+=`, or any kind of operator (other than comparisons, e.g. `<`, `>`, `==`) defined for it. It has other methods defined for moving the index. To increase the index 1 position, the code would look like this:  `string.index(i, offsetBy: 1)`

```
let string = "Some string"
var i = string.startIndex
i = string.index(i, offsetBy: 1)
```